# Jenkins server not restarting

Tags: jenkins

I have a jenkins server that I am trying to restart. I have tried the following options:

http://jenkins.server/restart

http://jenkins.server/safeRestart

http://jenkins.server/exit

and when I use the `uptime` command it outputs: `up 50 days, 2:00, 2 users, load average: 0.07, 0.05, 0.07`

I've tried to use the GUI to preform the restart and it results in the same thing. Does anybody have any ideas on what could be causing this?

Comment: Also tried using the 'safe restart' plugin and that had the same result

Comment: When you do restart from Jenkins you're not restarting the server it self, only the Jenkins program.

Comment: @JonS Okay - do you know how to restart the serve itself

Comment: @Joe.hail sudo reboot is what you are looking for

Comment: @Cosaquee are you saying do 'sudo <jenkinsurl>/restart?

Comment: You need to ssh to the server and use a user which has root access to do `sudo reboot`, you can't restart the server from the Jenkins service/program

Answer (score 1):

Open terminal of the server where Jenkins is installed and run below command as root:

```
service jenkins restart
```

or

```
service jenkins stop
service jenkins start
```

Answer (score 0):

You can stop and start jenkins service, It will force restart jenkins.

To open services type srvices.msc >> look for jenkins >> stop >> and start